# ScatterPlotItem crashs with 7000 or more points

Tags: python, numpy, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I use pyqt5.5.1, python 3.4 (windows 32 & 64 bits), numpy, pyqtgraph (tested develop git branch & lastest official version)

Here the part of code that I use to display a scatterplot

```
self.widget1 = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget();
self.widget1.hide();

self.p1 = self.widget1.addPlot()
n = 7300
s1 = pg.ScatterPlotItem(size=10, pen=pg.mkPen(None), brush=pg.mkBrush(0, 0, 255, 120))
pos = np.random.normal(size=(2,n), scale=1e-5)
s1.setData(pos[0], pos[1])
self.p1.addItem(s1)
self.widget1.show();
```

With n = 7, or 73, 730 scatterplot works.

but with n = 7300 and more, it crashs python.

I have only this trace, just before the crash:

```
QPaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that is being painted
R6025
- pure virtual function call
```

Could you help me to find a workaround or a fix ?

Thanks

Comment: I manage to run it, albeit a bit slow, with n=100000 on my machine. This is the exact code I used https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5846c697c14968d2ed0c

Comment: The issue is that you are trying to plot too many points (I've had this issue myself with more than 10k points). Try adding in OpenGL hardware (this may be buggy, or produce less than satisfactory results) acceleration or downsample.

The best way (in my opinion) would be to downsample, dynamically.